# Identical integration boundary limits in $ I=\int \sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

My Question is this:

let $ I=\int \sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx$

let $ u = x^2+1$

so $ dx= \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u-1}}$

and $ I=\int \frac{\sqrt{u} \ du}{2\sqrt{u-1}}$

suppose I want to evaluate $ I $ from $ x=-1$ to $ x = 1 $

this results in $ u = 2 $ for $ x=-1$ and $ u = 2 $ for $ x=1$

so if I want to evaluate

$ I = \int_{-1}^{1} {\sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx}=\int_{2}^{2} {\sqrt{u} \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u-1}}}$

This seem to suggest that the integral is zero but it is not

$ I = \sqrt 2 \ + sinh^{-1}(1)$

So what am I missing here

Comment: When $-1\leq x\leq1$ then $1\leq x^2+1\leq2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a change of variable that isn't one-to-one over the domain of integration. Instead you can split the integral over $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ and then apply the same change of variable.

An alternate way to see it is that you really have $dx=\frac{du}{\pm 2 \sqrt{u-1}}$, and the sign on the square root switches at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is not one-to-one. You are trying to use the equality$$\int_a^b\frac{f\bigl(g^{-1}(x)\bigr)}{g'\bigl(g^{-1}(x)\bigr)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$in a situation in which $g$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 1):

When $-1\leq x\leq1$ then $1\leq x^2+1\leq2$. Also the integrand is even function so 
$$I=2\int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt {x^2+1}\ dx}=\int_{1}^{2} {\frac{\sqrt{u}du}{\sqrt{u-1}}} = \sqrt 2 \ + \sinh^{-1}1$$